# HTML code question from an absolute beginner how to quickly have shortcuts for code for html images in html itself

Tags: html

I'll keep this simple. I'm an older gentleman and I don't really know how to code. I write an article every week on a WordPress site and I use basic html code (I don't control the site).. the article is super simple and repetitive (it's for an Australian fantasy football blog where I copy and paste in the teams whe  they are announced).

I have a lot of repeating elements (there are 18 teams, each team has a image reference banner).

Eg something like

```
<img src="httpss://website.com/photos/banner" alt="team1" width=100%/>
```

Is it possible to have all the image banner links stored in a permanent hidden code section and I can code short hand, I dunno something like.
"Link to Banner 1". Manually copying and pasting across the banner links is a slow process for me so I want to speed it up.

Havent really tries anything, I'm an absolute beginner.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question.  As it stands, it is a bit vague as to what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object element.

Your main page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


<h1>The object element</h1>

<object data="newLinks.html" width="500" height="600">
</object>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Between the object tag you can put a file including your links

For example your newLinks.html look like this

```
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2014422/pexels-photo-2014422.jpeg" alt="team1" width=100%/>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2014422/pexels-photo-2014422.jpeg" alt="team1" width=100%/>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2014422/pexels-photo-2014422.jpeg" alt="team1" width=100%/>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2014422/pexels-photo-2014422.jpeg" alt="team1" width=100%/>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2014422/pexels-photo-2014422.jpeg" alt="team1" width=100%/>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2014422/pexels-photo-2014422.jpeg" alt="team1" width=100%/>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2014422/pexels-photo-2014422.jpeg" alt="team1" width=100%/>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2014422/pexels-photo-2014422.jpeg" alt="team1" width=100%/>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2014422/pexels-photo-2014422.jpeg" alt="team1" width=100%/>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2014422/pexels-photo-2014422.jpeg" alt="team1" width=100%/>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2014422/pexels-photo-2014422.jpeg" alt="team1" width=100%/>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2014422/pexels-photo-2014422.jpeg" alt="team1" width=100%/>
```

Then you dont need to copy again and again all your image links, you need all your links only one time and then you can re use them only adding that  tag with your data file address.

Edit: Custom tag example

Creating your own tags

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <style>
        image-1 {
    content:url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/2014422/pexels-photo-2014422.jpeg);
    width: 100px; /*or your image's width*/
    height: 100px; /*or your image's height*/
    }
    image-2 {
    content:url(https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/beautiful-diverse-young-ladies-jeans-white-shirts-look-camera-beige-background-women-s-day-concept_197531-31813.jpg);
    width: 100px; /*or your image's width*/
    height: 100px; /*or your image's height*/
    }
    image-3 {
    content:url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/2014422/pexels-photo-2014422.jpeg);
    width: 100px; /*or your image's width*/
    height: 100px; /*or your image's height*/
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    
    <image-1></image-1>
    <image-2></image-2>
    <image-3></image-3>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I sort of understand, so how would I use the object to select one image at a time.

Eg. round 1 has team 3 vs team 7, I want to quickly code to have the banner for team 3 (then manually put in the teams in under that banner in a table, Im ok with doing that I just use an online html table maker) and then use code for the banner of team 7 (then manually include the teams). The way I currently do it is manually copy and post the links above.

handy to know I can use /object to link in another html page with set info.

Comment: I guess what I really want to be able to do is write someone as simple as (image 1) in the code and it places image 1 from an outside source. Do I need to use Javascript or something similar to do that?

Comment: I see, you can try using custom tags

check this example, custom tags can be short like this <image-1></image-1>

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mulnhd?file=index.html